# transition to several view controllers from collectionview

Tags: ios, swift

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showSoldi", sender: self)
    }
}
```

problem is that both view controllers get called.  First by the the segue itself, then by this code.  Any explanation ?

Answer (score 2):

Your segues are firing because you have wired them from the collection view's cells.  If you want to be able to call your segues from code, wire them from the viewController icon at the top of the viewController.

[image: How to wire segue from viewController]

By doing it this way, the segue will only fire when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`.